# Find the limits to compute volume on triple integral

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, volume

I have the following problem:

Let $0 ≤ R ≤ 1.$ Compute the volume of the following 3-dimensional shape: the intersection of the cylinder given by $x^2 + y^2 ≤ R^2$ and the ball of radius 1 centered at the origin.

We also got this clarification:
Think of R as any fixed value between 0 and 1. R is not the z coordinate. For every R there is a 3-D shape and a volume to compute. The answer is a function of R. For example, for R=1/2 you want the volume of the intersection of a cylinder of radius R and a ball of radius 1.

How can I set up this problem? I have no clue on how to approach it.

Comment: Can you picture the shape?  There is symmetry with the xy-plane.  If you use cylindrical coordinates, what would the upper bound on the z-value be?

Comment: The shape is like a sphere inside a bigger sphere and you are trying to find the difference between them right?

Comment: No, it's more like a grain silo, a cylinder with a rounded top (and bottom).

Comment: @PaulSundheim How do you know that

Comment: The problem states "the intersection of the cylinder ... and the ball"

Comment: @PaulSundheim So, how can I move to get the limits? Do I just pick an arbitrary R?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $R$ be fixed at some value $0 < R \le 1$.  Then the upper limit on $z$ would be $z= \sqrt{1-(x^2 + y^2)}$. In cylindrical coordinates this would be $z = \sqrt{1-r^2}$.  The limits on $r$ would then be $0 \le r \le R$ and $0 \le \theta \le 2 \pi$.  If you use $0$ for the lower limit on $z$ and then multiply the integral by $2$, you will have the answer.  Can you write the integral now?